When does the loop in c programming gives infinite result I am not able to understand it?
include<stdio.h>
int main(){
int i = 1;
while(1)
{
printf("%d \n",i);
--i;
}


When i run this code why does it give infinite results as what i think is that the code should get ended after printing 5 4 3 2 1 bcz i am using decrement operator
so it should end up when i becomes zero  because 0 is considered as false

Try this:           while(i)

The reason the loop continues forever is because the while(1) statement contains a constant 1  -- and since a constant cannot change, the while loop continues forever because the check that is done on the value 1 always returns true.  Like Konstantin Makarov already told, pls try while(i)  ( using variable i ).  Because i is a variable, it can change, and therefore the loop can eventually break when the check on the variable returns false.

Because there's a difference between the lowercase letter i and the numeric value 1. The variable i is supposed to control the loop, and it's the value you're decrementing in the loop. The numeric value 1 is a constant that will never change, and therefore cannot be used to control the loop. Proofread your code, or learn to use the debugger to step through the code as it runs, where you can catch logic errors like this one.

Note that i is a bad (albeit common) choice for a variable name. It is confusingly similar to 1, it doesn't indicate its meaning, and it is impossible to search for.

@stark If you cannot tell i and 1 (and o and 0) apart then you need to use a better font, i.e. fix the root cause instead of working around the symptom.
